# Problem when I try to display a json (array into an object ) in angular 2

Tags: json, angular, object, provider

Im try to create a simple page and I have this problem when I  I try to show my json file in my component.html

This is the json file.

```
{
  "example": {
    "cat": [
      {
        "title": "title 1",
        "href": "#cat0"
      },
      {
        "title": "title 1",
        "href": "#cat1"
      },
      {
        "title": "title 1",
        "href": "#cat1"
      },
      {
        "title": "title 1",
        "href": "#cat1"
      },
      {
        "title": "title 1",
        "href": "#cat1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the Interface.

```
export interface menuExample {
    example?:{
        cat?:{
            title: string,
            href: string
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Service.

```
export class serviceMenu {

    info: menuExample= {};
    cargada = false;
    team: any[] = [];

    constructor( private http: HttpClient) { 

      this.loadMenu();

    }


    private loadMenu() {

      this.http.get('assets/json/file.json')
      .subscribe( (resp: any[]) => {

        this.cargada = true;
        this.team = resp;

      });  
    }
  }
```

And this is the html file

```
<li *ngFor="let menudetails of serviceMenu.info.example?.cat" class="side-nav__item">
 <a href="{{menudetails.href}}" class="side-nav__link">
    <span>{{menudetails.title}}</span>
 </a>
</li>
```

Then I import my file and I did all but I don't understand the mistake :S

`ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HeaderComponent -> serviceMenu ]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HeaderComponent -> serviceMenu ]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for serviceMenu !`

Only I try to show my json with an NgFor and show the title and href, nothing else.
Someone could help me or provide a better and easy solution?
Thanks a lot!

Estefa

Comment: have you include provider in `AppModule` for `serviceMenu `?

Answer (score 0):

You need add `@Injectable()` in `serviceMenu` class and add `providers: [ serviceMenu ]` in `AppModule` class

Comment: Thanks Hien, I fixed one part with your solution! @Injectable() 
:D

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your service in your appmodule or in your component

```
import {serviceMenu} from '<your service path>'
@Component({
    selector: 'componentName',
    templateUrl: './componentName.html',
    providers: [serviceMenu]
})
```

or you can also add your service in providers section in appmodule.ts

```
import {serviceMenu} from '<your service path>'
providers: [serviceMenu]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Yash I fix one part with your solution, i'm very beginner with angular :D

Comment: it would be great if you accept my answer :) :)

Comment: this was my first question, I don't have permission for do this for the moment :P only I have 4 points

Answer (score 0):

Error look like you have missed `providers` in `AppModule`. you need to add service in `AppModule`

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [];
imports: [];
providers: [ serviceMenu ]  // like this
})
```

Comment: @Estefa77 its my pleasure to help you